# Windows forgets window position on multiple monitors after a while

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I'm using Windows 7 Professional and I have two monitors connected to the computer, one via VGA (monitor 1) and one via DVI (monitor 2). The VGA one is my main monitor.

On the VGA cable there's a KVM switch, and I can switch it to a laptop. Whenever I do this, all the windows from the PC are gathered on the monitor 2.

Now, when I switch the KVM back to the PC after a few minutes, all my windows are restored to the monitors they've been on previously. However, when I wait a little longer (I can't really quantify it), all the windows are gathered on monitor 1.

To give an example: I work on the PC. I have Windows Explorer open on monitor 1 and Word on monitor 2. I switch the KVM to my laptop. Explorer and Word are gathered on monitor 2. After a while, I switch back to the PC. All the windows are gathered on monitor 1. But I want them to be laid out like before.

Apparently there is a timeout somewhere, after which Windows forgets the window position or distribution to the monitors. Can I disable this timeout or make it longer?